# Switching between JPanels on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

At the moment just for testing purposes I would like to change the JPanel on the JFrame every time it is clicked. I am cycling through 3 panels/pages each with their unique background color.

Currently it will change but only paint when it comes to the very first panel that was added otherwise display the default gray.

Code:

```
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        mainFrame.changePage();
    }

public void changePage() {
    if(currentPage != null) {
        this.remove(currentPage);
    }
    currentPage = pages[pageNumber];
    this.add(currentPage);
    currentPage.setPage();
    super.repaint();
    pageNumber++;
    if(pageNumber > 2) {
        pageNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` to swap panels. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and examples to get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the comment from @camickr to use `CardLayout`, you need to `revalidate`. Change:

```
super.repaint();
```

to

```
revalidate();
```

Comment: And the reason you need the revalidate() is because the layout manager only sets the size/location of the original panel that you display. When you swap panels you need the revalidate() method to invoke the layout manager so the current panel can now be given a size/location. Or instead you can use the API so you don't reinvent the wheel. The CardLayout does all this for you so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I don't understand why this hasn't been marked as the accepted answer yet

Comment: @nix_s *Thanks, it works with revalidate() now!* - it may fix the problem, but it should NOT be the solution you use. Learn to use Swing the way it was designed and don't reinvent the wheel. You still haven't acknowledge that you have read up on the `CardLayout` in an attempt to understand why it should be used. The `CardLayout` even supports "next" functionality so you don't even need to track which panel you are on. If you use the API properly you will have less problems in the future.

Comment: Understood. I will now attempt to implement the CardLayout and come back if I have any problems. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Since @camickr mentioned my code below does not adhere to best practices, please refer the following link on how to use the CardLayout.

[How to use CardLayout - The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

[Associated Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/index.html#CardLayoutDemo)

---

> just for testing purposes

Keeping emphasis on the above, here's some sample code. This is **NOT** production grade, just a POC without needing the CardLayout mentioned by @camickr.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FirstSwingExample {  
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Swinger s = new Swinger();
    }
  
}

class Swinger implements ActionListener {
    
    int currFrame = 1;
    JFrame f;
    JLabel lblPanelOne, lblPanelTwo, lblPanelThree;
    JPanel panelOne, panelTwo, panelThree;
    JButton b;
    
    public Swinger() {
        setup();
    }
    
    private void setup() {
        
        f=new JFrame();
        
        panelOne = new JPanel();
        lblPanelOne = new JLabel("Panel One");
        panelOne.setBounds(0,0,100, 40);
        panelOne.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelOne.add(lblPanelOne);
        
        
        panelTwo = new JPanel();
        lblPanelTwo = new JLabel("Panel Two");
        panelTwo.setBounds(0,0,100, 40);
        panelTwo.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panelTwo.add(lblPanelTwo);
        
        panelThree = new JPanel();
        lblPanelThree = new JLabel("Panel Three");
        panelThree.setBounds(0,0,100, 40);
        panelThree.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panelThree.add(lblPanelThree);
        
        b=new JButton("Panel Two");
        b.setBounds(130,100,100, 40);
        b.setActionCommand("click");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        
        panelOne.setVisible(true);
        f.add(panelOne);
        f.add(b);

        f.setSize(400,500);  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("click")) {
            switch(currFrame) {
                case 1:
                    panelOne.setVisible(false);
                    f.remove(panelOne);
                    panelTwo.setVisible(true);
                    f.add(panelTwo);
                    b.setText("Panel Three");
                    currFrame++;
                    break;
                
                case 2:
                    panelTwo.setVisible(false);
                    f.remove(panelTwo);
                    f.add(panelThree);
                    panelThree.setVisible(true);
                    b.setText("Panel One");
                    currFrame++;
                    break;
            
                default:
                    panelThree.setVisible(false);
                    f.remove(panelThree);
                    f.add(panelOne);
                    panelOne.setVisible(true);
                    b.setText("Panel Two");
                    currFrame = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Don't reinvent the wheel. Don't use a switch statement to swap panels. What if you have 10 panels?? The code gets messy and is not maintainable. Learn to use the existing API's to keep the code simple and maintainable.

Comment: @camickr I already clarified at the very beginning that this was just a proof of concept. Please read my answer fully. I would appreciate if you could please withdraw the downvote.

Comment: This is a poor answer for the reasons given in my comment. I do not recommend anybody follow this approach to solving the problem.